# Finding elements in array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a model of products which has many components. Some components are optional and depend on the choice the user is making to enable them or not. 
I have two models, one is configuration and the other is elements (of that configuration).

At the beginning I bring all the elements of the array, and then create another array of those which will be shown by default. 
But when I write the following code it gives me an error despite both objects being arrays of hashes.

So I bring my first array of all elements:

```
irb(main):252:0*  @all = Configuration.find(1).elements
 => [#<Element id: 1, name: "elem1", quantity: 1, position: 1, subposition: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>, #<Element id: 2, name: "elem2", quantity: 2, position: 2, subposition: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>, #<Element id: 3, name: "elem3", quantity: 3, position: 2, subposition: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>, #<Element id: 4, name: "elem4", quantity: 4, position: 3, subposition: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>]
```

Then I filter to be only those that have a subposition nil or 1

```
irb(main):253:0> @default = @all.where(:subposition=>nil).concat(@all.where(:subposition=>1))
=> [#<Element id: 1, name: "elem1", quantity: 1, position: 1, subposition: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>, #<Element id: 4, name: "elem4", quantity: 4, position: 3, subposition: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>, #<Element id: 2, name: "elem2", quantity: 2, position: 2, subposition: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>]
```

So far so good, as you can see, Elem3 is not being shown in @default as it doesn't meet the requiements.

The problem comes when I try to play with the arrays as I need to perform certain operations.

```
irb(main):257:0> @all.where(:position =>1)
=> [#<Element id: 1, name: "elem1", quantity: 1, position: 1, subposition: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, configuration_id: 1>]
```

But the same operation in @default will fail,

```
irb(main):258:0> @default.where(:position =>1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x2641660>
```

Now, they're both arrays of hashes and look the same, why is the same method failing in the second case?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout your code, `@all` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an array. This lets you perform the standard `.where` call (among others). When you assigned to `@default`, you used `.concat` which evaluated the query and assigned an actual array to `@default`.

You might try a different approach in your second code block. Maybe something like this:

```
@default = @all.where("subposition is null or subposition = ?", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is that concat transforms a collection into an array.

I'd replace:

```
irb(main):253:0> @default = @all.where(:subposition=>nil).concat(@all.where(:subposition=>1))
```

by:

```
@default = @all.where("subposition = '1' OR subposition = nil") #I'm unsure of the nil in the statement, I nerver remember, try NULL if it fails
```

This way, you make only one db query and you keep an ActiveRecord collection.

Thus, you'll be able to chain other where conditions on it.